# flask: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn flask using an online tutorial and when I trying to register a user with following formpayload data,

```
csrf_token=ImJkOTlkYmVlMWQ2N2MwZGVmMGQ5MTRkZmZhODBmY2E0NWFiYTY4Y2Ei.DZIZ_w.UTdQ_hkzHXoIFS8oH8D84AMWLF8&username=vector&email=vcks%40xyz.com&password=1234&password2=1234&submit=Register
```

and when I hit submit i get following traceback

```
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/microblog/app/routes.py", line 51, in register
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/flasky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/flasky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/flasky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/flasky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 204, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/Users/vaibhavchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/flasky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 224, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

as requested I am adding code for Registration Form.

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[(DataRequired(), EqualTo('password'))])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('please use diffrent username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('please use diffrent email.')
```

Comment: added code for RegistrationForm

Comment: indenting was fixed as i failed to provide right spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
password2 = PasswordField(
    'Repeat Password', validators=[(DataRequired(), EqualTo('password'))])
```

That `validators` is supposed to be a list of validators. But instead, you're passing a list with a tuple of two validators. To fix it:

```
password2 = PasswordField(
    'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
```

Inside `validate()`, it does something like (simplified pseudocode):

```
for field in fields:
    for validator in field.validators:
        validator(field)
```

So the first `validator` for the `password2` field ends up as a tuple of two functions, instead of a function, and you can't call a tuple.

Comment: if you don't mind telling me how were you able to figure out validators required a list, and my passing a tuple was bug? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan Well, the other ones (with only one validator) are passing a list of one validator, not a list of a tuple of one validator. That inconsistency seemed strange. Plus, from the exception description, clearly somewhere the code is trying to use a tuple as a function, and it makes sense how the former could cause the latter. So I did a quick search for some flask_wtf sample code… and couldn't find any with multiple validators. So I looked at the source (much easier to find), which confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan Normally it would be even simpler, but this particular kind of inconsistency is sometimes legal in Python (`'%d: %d' % (1, 2)` requires a tuple, but `'%d: done' % 1` works without one…), which is why I had to double-check.

Comment: inconsistency as in working with tuples and it's  behavior, also I looked at the documentation for code, wtforms/fields/core.py", line 224 this is the closest to understanding why this function needs an iterable after your explanation
        """
        Run a validation chain, stopping if any validator raises StopValidation.

        :param form: The Form instance this field beongs to.
        :param validators: a sequence or iterable of validator callables.
        :return: True if validation was stopped, False otherwise.
        """

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan Yeah, inconsistency as in if it takes a list of tuples (or an iterable of iterables), why did the ones that just pass a flat list work? As for the docs, Flask docs seem to take the requests/bs4 style to the extreme: lots of examples to make it really easy to write your first program with it, but very little depth on the actual reference. That’s why I went right to the source—which is mostly readable and nicely organized. It just loops over the validator chain and calls things, with no nested loop.